# Swift filter tableviewcell array count

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to show data in cell. I filtered arrays by Boolean and date.
When I print “cell.titleLabel.text”, I get 5 labels in row. (You can see in my code). 3 labels text color are red, 1 black and 1 gray.

I get 5 data, but 3 data are past times. How can I get these 3 data as Int(count)?

My code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RestCell
    
    cell.titleLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.docIdLabel.text = docIdArray[indexPath.row]
    
    let isoDate = dateArray[indexPath.row]
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
    
    let rowArrayValue = completedArray[indexPath.row]
    
    if rowArrayValue == false {

        cell.checkboxButton.setOn(false, animated: true)

        if date < Date() {
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                            
            print("Label Name is : \(cell.titleLabel.text!)")
            //Label Name is : Test1
            //Label Name is : Test2
            //Label Name is : Test3
            
        } else {
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                            
            print("Label Name is : \(cell.titleLabel.text!)")
            //Label Name is : Test4
        }
    } else {
        
        cell.checkboxButton.setOn(true, animated: true)
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
                    
        print("Label Name is : \(cell.titleLabel.text!)")
        //Label Name is : Test5
    }
    
    cell.buttonTapped = {
        
        if cell.checkboxButton.on == true {
            cell.checkboxButton.setOn(true, animated: true)
            tableView.reloadData()
                            
        } else {
            cell.checkboxButton.setOn(false, animated: true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why're you not using `completedArray` for that?

Comment: It shows as count: 5

Comment: Where do you want to get the count? Kindly elaborate your problem statement,

Answer (score 0):

Use **`compare(_:)`** on the `date` obtained using `DateFormatter` for filtering out the dates before the current date and then get the `count`,

```
let pastDatesCount = dateArray.compactMap {(date) -> Date? in
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date), date.compare(Date()) == .orderedAscending {
        return date
    }
    return nil
}.count
```

Comment: It works, but if array value changes (rowArrayValue == true), it shows still 3, instead of 2.

Comment: Do you not want to show pastDates rows in your table? I'm unable to understand the actual thing you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: But if the rowArrayValue changes, I don't wanna show in (rowArrayValue == true), label color must be another color(gray).

Comment: When is the `rowArrayValue` changing?

Comment: when the checkbox tapped.

Comment: Where are you changing its state then? Add the screenshot.

Comment: Starting with Swift 3, Date objects are Comparable and Equatable. It is perfectly valid now to say `if date1 < date2`, or in the OPs case, `if date < Date()`. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: This code also creates a new date formatter for every date it needs to compare, which Apple recommends against doing.